# Check url stored in variable to current url

Tags: jquery, url, location, href, attr

I can't find out why this is not working:

```
var myurl = "http://domain.com";
var currenturl = $(location).attr('href');
if (myurl == currenturl) {
...
```

Both myurl and currenturl are the same, yet the script in the if statement is not get executed.

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myurl = "http://domain.com";
var currenturl = window.location.href;
//alert(currenturl);
    if (myurl === currenturl) {
        alert('should see this');
    } else {
    }
});
```

SOLUTION:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myurl = "http://domain.com/"; // see the slash at the end
    if (myurl == location.href) {
        alert('that ss the same page');
    } else {
    }
});
```

Any suggestion?
Thans.

Comment: what is `location`? is it `window.location`?

Comment: Or were you looking for $("#location")?

Comment: do you mean `window.location.href`?

Comment: Added the full snippet, doesn't work. `currenturl` should be the page the visitor is on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to use jQuery for it, just:

```
if (myurl == location.href) {
    // the same
}
```

If that doesn't work, make sure they're both the same by debugging their values:

```
console.log(myurl, location.href);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked: myurl lacked a `/` while location href had it.

Comment: @elbatron glad to hear you found the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't work anyway, because you can't compare objects in JavaScript like that. The fact that $(location) is almost certainly undefined will be a problem. See: [Object comparison in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript)

If you are using a local file, you should add "file://" to the URL

```
<html>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
google.load('jquery', '1.7.2');
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
var myurl = "file://somedir/test.html";
var currenturl = window.location.href;
//alert(currenturl);
    if (myurl === currenturl) {
        alert('should see this');
    } else {
        alert ('see other thing');
    }
});


</script>
<body>
hi
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually, `$(location).attr('href')` does work ... not sure how cross-browser it is though; doesn't take away the fact that it's just plain silly

Comment: I just tried it with `$(location).attr('href')` and it works, also tried with `location.href` and that works as well.